# how to save customer address attribute after order success event in Magengto 2?

Tags: customer-address, magento2.3.5, customer-address-attribute

I have added a new shipping address (without saving it in the address book) on the checkout page to place an order.

I want to update the existing default shipping address value (zone attribute only) from the new address after the order is successful.

I have used an event:  `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action`

> Observer code to set the zone attribute value

```
$addressFactory  = $this->objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory');
$address = $addressFactory->create();

        if($orderedZone != $existingZone && $existingZone != ''){
            $address->setZone($newZone);
            $address->save($address);
        }
```

But after this code I am getting an error like this:

```
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception): "Country" is a required value.
"First Name" is a required value.
"Last Name" is a required value.
"Zip/Postal Code" is a required value.
"Street Address" is a required value.
```

These fields are already set in the default shipping address.

how can I set only the zone attribute from the new address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the code like this one.

```
    protected $_customerFactory;
    protected $_addressFactory;
 
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory $addressFactory)
    {
        $this->_customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->_addressFactory = $addressFactory;
    }
 
    //PASS Your CUSTOMER ID here instade of 32
    $customer = $customerFactory->create()->load(32);    
 
    //Shipping Address
    $shippingAddressId = $customer->getDefaultShipping();
    $shippingAddress = $this->_addressFactory->create()->load($shippingAddressId);

    //now you can update your address here and don't forget to save
    $shippingAddress->setZone("YOURNEWVALUE");
    $shippingAddress->save();
```

Comment: Thank You. this is working fine. I was doing the mistake of Shipping ID

Comment: I need to add this Zone attribute value in the customer address block in the customer dashboard. check the screenshot:  https://nimb.ws/ziaOhB 

Also, I tried to add a zone column in the address grid but there is no value is getting there. I have tried to print the address array inside this loop: <?php foreach ($_pAddsses as $address) :   print_r($address->getData());?> but print_r is not working and page not working